# $x^n + y^n = (2y-x)^n$ (number theory)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $x, y,n \space(≥2)$ such that

$$ x^n + y^n = (2y-x)^ n$$

From Fermat's Last Theorem, the answer must be $(x,y,n) = (3a,4a,2)　$

I attacked this problem but I can't make any progress.

Other than setting　$\gcd(x,y)=1$, and expanding the right side $(2y-x)^n$ and comparing some terms,
there is not much to do.

Can you solve this problem with only elementary method(not using FLT)?

Comment: From the FLT, you won't find solutions for $n>2$. So there is no point trying $n>2$. Solve $x^2+y^2=(2y-x)^2$, which is easy.

Comment: I mean with only elementary method (olympiad level technique.)

Comment: You should have said it upfront.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem is not elementary, really, you're just supposed to know it and maybe use it in a setting such as a math Olympiad. As for the actual claim, this is correct.

Comment: Fermat's last is overrated $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ implies only primes exponents need to be checked. $h^p\equiv h\pmod {p}$ if $p$ is prime, implies it must work in linear form for all primes dividing any composite $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $y=x+k$, where we can assume $\gcd(x,k)=1$ since our stuff is homogenous.

We require $x^n + (x+k)^n = (x+2k)^n$ and looking at it $\bmod k$ we get $x^n + x^n \equiv x^n\bmod k$ and so $x^n \equiv 0 \bmod k$ which implies $k=1$.

Now write it as $y^n = (y+1)^n - (y-1)^n$ and apply lte on any odd prime dividing $y$ to get  to get $v_p(y^n) > v_p((y+1)^n - (y-1)^n)$.

So just the case when $y$ is a power of $2$ remains. If $y$ is $2$ we check it by hand, if $y=4$ you can use lte and $n=2$ checks out, for $y>4$ you can use lte and it checks out.